# How to use Grid Layout manager for arranging two buttons in desried location in frame?

Tags: python, grid, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have been started Learning TK (From Python). I felt that i could use Grid Layout manager for displaying widgets (It sounds easy) but now i am feeling it was a wrong decision. For example i was just planning a frame which inside it was having multiple frames (Wizard Like form). So in the bottom of that form i wanted to have two buttons (Next, Previous). Now i wanted to place them on the very right of the bottom frame, but it seems to be difficult in having such an arrangement.

i tried creating seperate internal frames for both the buttons but could not get my result. Can some one tell me if i can achieve such a result with grid layout manager

```
from Tkinter import *
tk = Tk()
main_frame = Frame(tk)
main_frame.grid(row=0)
frame3 = Frame(main_frame, bg="orange", width=1000, height=100)
frame3.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=2)
frame3a = Frame(frame3)
frame3b = Frame(frame3)
frame3a.grid(row =0 ,column = 0)
frame3b.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
btn1 = Button(frame3a, text='Next', width = 10, command=next)
btn1.grid(padx=200, pady =40 )
btn2 = Button(frame3b, text='Previous', width = 10, command=prev)
btn2.grid(padx=00, pady =40 )
frame3.grid_propagate(False)
tk.mainloop()
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

yes you can.  Use more row/column attributes from grid as well as the sticky attribute.

Read: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm

I am assuming you want your window to look something like this (crude ascii incoming)

```
+------------+------------+
|            |            |
|  FRAME     |    FRAME   |
|------------+------------|
|        FRAME  |PREV|NEXT|
+-------------------------+
```

To do this I would use `pack` rather than `grid`.  I make a bottom frame and make it just the height of the buttons, then pack them both right:  If you want to stick other crap in that bottom sace, you can use grid manager to shove the frame out of the way.  Pack is only active in the frame with the buttons in it, but you can use gridmanager to move the buttonframe around.

```
from Tkinter import * 
tk = Tk() 
main_frame = Frame(tk) 
main_frame.grid(row=0) 
frame1 = Frame(main_frame, bg="orange", width=500, height=100)
frame2 = Frame(main_frame, bg="blue", width=500, height=100)
frame3 = Frame(main_frame, bg="green", width=1000, height=50)
frame1.grid(row=1,column=1)
frame2.grid(row=1,column=2) 
frame3.grid(row=2,column=1,columnspan=2)
frame3.pack_propagate(0) # Keeps bottom frame from resizing
btn1 = Button(frame3, text='Next', width = 10) 
btn1.pack(side='right')  # sticks on side
btn2 = Button(frame3, text='Previous', width = 10) 
btn2.pack(side='right')  # sticks on side
tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, i have used that as a refernce only. Could you please help me to arrange it in the given example.

Comment: Kind of yes, both the buttons be in same row like software installations wizards....

Comment: Yes that worked, actually i wanted to achieve the whole thing using grid layout manager only.

Comment: You can do it with just grid, and since empty “frames” don't actually need a widget there; the widget underneath just shows through, which is usually good enough. _However_, I don't know if Tkinter hides this capability.